# Have to create 100 different "Execute SQL Task"s in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there anyway to do this in code so I don't have to drag little boxes, click on each one, select the parameters, click, click, copy, paste, click, drag align repeat?

Comment: When you say different , what do you mean ? different columns? Different tables? Different parameters? If the columns / tables are the same you can probably do it with a loop , if everything is different nope :)

Comment: Yes, doctor, there is. However: Google will give you the answer. This forum is for code issues with code attached.

Comment: [Biml](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A181965+%5Bssis%5D+biml). Automate the bejezus out of it and it's trivial to do so

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough details on what you want to loop on but it sounds like you can use a for loop container and have the for loop change at each iteration. You may also want to look at the for each container. One of the two will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You look into "reading data" from an excel/csv file in which you will make columns according to your parameters you need. Map those parameters into variables and include this task in a loop to go row by row in your file. Map the sql query in a variable in which you select or do whatever you need to do and inside this query you are going to use the parameters mapped to variables mentioned above. This should work!